# How to create custom basic type in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, types, customization, qml

I don't seem to find any resources on adding basic types to QML. I don't mean QObject or higher derived elements, but the basic types - bool, int, real and so on.

Didn't have any luck digging for it in the sources as well...

So any info is appreciated.

Comment: What basic type are you trying to implement? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you want to register more complex types than int, bool, real, since they are already present.

You cannot do this in Qt 4.x.  It is possible in Qt 5 (QML 2), but there is no public API.  If you still want to do it, you'll need to dig into some code to see how its done, as there's no documentation.

You need to implement a QQmlValueTypeProvider (qqmlglobal_p.h) and create QQmlValueTypeBase<> subclasses (qqmlvaluetype_p.h) for each of your types.  Then register your value type provider with QQml_addValueTypeProvider() in your plugin's registerTypes().

One example you could look at are QGeoCoordinate, QGeoRectangle, etc. from QtLocation module: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtlocation/trees/master/src/imports/location

Good luck.

Comment: Funny how QML makes some tedious things easy and some easy things tedious... Gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/custom-types.html) and [this article](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#using-enumerations-of-a-custom-type) about how to create custom types in Qt/QML. As far as creating your own primitive types (int, bool, double, etc)... I don't think this is a possibility without digging into the source code of the Qt language itself and I don't think that's a good idea.

What purpose would there be to making your own primitive type? Why can't you use the ones already defined by the language itself?

If what you are trying to do is renaming a primitive type, there is always an option to do a **typedef**. "The purpose of typedef is to assign alternative names to existing types, most often those whose standard declaration is cumbersome, potentially confusing, or likely to vary from one implementation to another."

Comment: I think it is pretty clear why you got a downvote - your answer provides information that is not only unrelated, but also well known to me. As of why you downvoted the one good answer and the question itself... now that is curious...

Comment: @ddriver Didn't downvote anything. I think I may have misunderstood your question since you made reference to basic types in your posted question which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well, if you didn't I really wonder who did... and backpedaled on it in a few minutes. Apologies if it wasn't you.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you found an answer that suffices.

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.5 you can create basic types by using [Q_GAGDET](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_GADGET). For example you can create a custom MyError class:

```
class MyError
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_ENUMS(ErrorType)

    Q_PROPERTY(bool suppressed READ suppressed WRITE setSupressed)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString message READ message WRITE setMessage)
    Q_PROPERTY(ErrorType type READ type WRITE setType)

public:
    enum ErrorType {
        Warning, //Survex should still run
        Fatal, //Survex will not run
        Unknown
    };

    cwSurveyChunkError();
    cwSurveyChunkError(const cwSurveyChunkError &);
    cwSurveyChunkError &operator=(const cwSurveyChunkError &);
    ~cwSurveyChunkError();

    ErrorType type() const;
    void setType(ErrorType type);

    QString message() const;
    void setMessage(QString message);

    bool suppressed() const;
    void setSupressed(bool suppressed);

private:
    QSharedDataPointer<MyErrorData> data;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyError) //Allows you to use this class in QVariant
```

You need to register the type with qml, using qmlRegisterUncreatableType. This allows you to use MyError.ErrorType enums in QML. Since MyError is a Q_GADGET you can pass it to QML directly and use MyError properties, as if it was a QObject. Q_GADGET object's are lighter weight versions of QObject except they can't be created in QML, and signals and slots don't work in them.

QML example:

```
Item {

   Component.onCompleted: {
        var error = model.errorAt(4); //Returns MyError 
        console.log("Error:" + error.type + " " + error.message + " " + error.suppressed)
   }
}
```

Comment: While there is value to this answer, it doesn't really address the issue of creating basic QML types, which do not have properties, enums or whatsoever. This brings meta support for non QObject derived objects. There is a subtle difference.

Comment: I guess, if you trying to create something like Qt.rect() or Qt.point() this is probably the best way to do it. QML pretty much supports all the super basic types like int, bool, double, etc...